# Maven pluginManagement multiple parent

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am trying to setup maven plugin management for a multi-module project. My project structure looks something like this

```
base_project
   -- pom.xml
   -- projectA
        -- pom.xml
        -- projectB
             -- pom.xml
        -- projectC
             -- pom.xml 
   -- project D
        -- pom.xml
```

In the pom.xml of the base project, I have defined a plugin in PluginManagement

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

I want projectA to inherit the pluginManagement so that I can use the plugin in projectB and projectC. What I want is that when I build base_project, the plugin should only run for projectB, projectC and projectD and not for projectA. projectA should just inherit the pluginManagement of base_project. I tried two type of setup but no luck

**Setup 1**

With this setup, spring-boot-maven-plugin does't run when projectB or projectC gets build

projectA pom.xml looks like

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

while projectB and projectC pom.xml looks like

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

**Setup 2**

With this setup, spring-boot-maven-plugin also runs against projectA.

projectA pom.xml looks like

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

while projectB and projectC pom.xml looks like

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: 1- which goal are you trying to execute ??   2- take a look at the effective Pom of your child pom it will show how your pom really look like [help:effective-pom]

Comment: Got it worked. We don't need to define the plugin in projectA's pom.xml. We can directly use it in child pom.

Answer (score 0):

Got it worked. We don't need to define the plugin in projectA's pom.xml. We can directly use it in child pom.